# select sections which do not have any students enrolled

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I want to select all sections which do not have any students enrolled

These are the three tables:

`ENROLLMENTS
student_id, section_id`

`SECTIONS
course_id, section_id`

`COURSES
course_id, description`

The output table should look like this:
`course_id  |  description  |  section_id`

I'm not shure which join to use.

Answer (score 0):

So you want

```
SELECT
    course_id
    , description
    , section_id
FROM
    COURSES
INNER JOIN
    SECTIONS
ON
    COURSES.course_id = SECTIONS.course_id
LEFT JOIN
    ENROLLMENTS
ON
    ENROLLMENTS.section_id = SECTIONS.section_id
WHERE
    ENROLLMENTS.student_id IS NULL;
```

This will take all of the information from `COURSES` and `SECTIONS`, then join it to `ENROLLMENTS`, keeping all of the information for `COURSES` and `SECTIONS` where there an no enrollments. Then by selecting where the `ENROLLMENTS` `student_id` is `NULL` we find all the entries that didn't have `section_id`s in `SECTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a subquery?

```
SELECT
    sections.course_id,
    courses.description,
    sections.section_id
FROM
    courses INNER JOIN sections ON courses.course_id = sections.course_id
WHERE
    courses.section_id NOT IN (SELECT section_id FROM enrollments)
```